# Error while trying to find an element by Xpath in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#submit-6359ad565c26651cca764d4e291dca49"}

On this website: https://provide-journey-contact-details.homeoffice.gov.uk/next, I get the error for the 'Save and Continue' button, i tried finding it by xpath, then by css selector, but it does not work. What should I do? Please help.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_address).send_keys("almacompexim@yahoo.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_verify).send_keys("almacompexim@yahoo.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(password).send_keys("Alin1234")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_verify).send_keys("Alin1234")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, 'submit')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Page cannot be found...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't open that page, but I guess you are missing a wait / delay before accessing that element.
Also, the `6359ad565c26651cca764d4e291dca49` suffix may be dynamic.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'submit')]"))).click()
```

In case the element is initially out of the visible screen, you will have to scroll to it first.
Like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'submit')]")))
time.sleep(0.5)
actions.move_to_element(button).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
button.click()
```

**UPD**
The unique XPath for that element is

```
//div[contains(@style,'display')]//div[contains(@style,'display')]//input[@value='Save and continue' and @type='submit']
```

You may use shorter locators that will work too, but this is locating that button uniquely.
So, your code to click that button can be:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@style,'display')]//div[contains(@style,'display')]//input[@value='Save and continue' and @type='submit']"))).click()
```

Comment: Please put your code inside the question to make it readable

Comment: Anyway, that page is not presented to us. Maybe it is restricted to UK IPs only

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk. This is the website, you scroll down a bit, press start now and just check the no boxes until you see a page where you need to put the email and password

Comment: Now I see. Please check the updated answer

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, and sorry if I took your time, I am pretty much a beginner!:)

Comment: It's OK, you are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer